# Slow server performance

Tags: performance, docker

I ran the following command *strace -c ./docker-compose --version &> trace.txt* and got the following output

[image]

I then followed up with another strace command to output all the system call and there is only 1 line in the trace as follow:

*wait4(-1, docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471 [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 1925*

Does anyone know what this line means? I am trying to troubleshoot a very sluggish server and running docker-compose --version took me like 12-15secs to see the output. The one thing i do get now is that this call is taking almost half of the time to run the program.

This doesn't seems like acceptable performance to me, given that the server has Xeon processor with 144GB RAM and an empty ubuntu.

Comment: The total time here is 1.3 seconds. Where's the 12-15secs?

Comment: It my own timing from the moment i hit enter on the keyboard until the program exits.  This is not a Docker problem but some underlying hardware issue i feel. The issue is that the wait4 call seems to hang for very long. I think i saw > 10secs in one of my trace.